# Addition of two sets of selectors in one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add to sets of selectors to one set.

*For example:*

`$("div")` gives me all sets of div and `$("span")` gives me all sets of span.

Now I want to add them to form one set of selectors which contain all spans and divs.

Avoid to advice for adding class, I need to merge this two sets only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method.

```
$('div').add('span').DoYourStuffWithBoth();
```

or

```
var divs = $('div');
var spans = $('span');
divs.add(spans).DoYourStuffWithBoth();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine multiple selector using comma between them like this

```
$("div, span")
```

Comment: Hi,Iam doing it like var a = $("div"); var b = $("span"); var c= $(a,b) should be combination of a and b. it is not working in this case

Answer (score 1):

jQuery selectors are basically css selectors. You combine two selectors by comma separation:

```
$("span, div");
```

Comment: var c= $(a,b) is not correct syntax as a and b are array of elements not selector

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the combined selector:

```
jQuery('div, span')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
$('div, span')
```

Should give you a set of elements with both div's and span's

Comment: Hi,Iam doing it like var a = $("div"); var b = $("span"); var c= $(a,b) should be combination of a and b. it is not working in this case

Comment: Why doing it the difficult way if $('div, span') will give you exactly what you need? Anyway, you can use $.extend() if you like to do it your way.

Comment: no div span was example, i have to apply this on two selectors which are coming after some processing then i need to merge them